# retweeting by twitter.com/intent/retweet vs twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to add retweet button to my website and I have two option:

I can create application in twitter and go through all steps and when user click retweet he should first authorize my app then after his authorization I can use twitter4j to retweet on his account

BUT:

the simpler way is to use this the following:

```
<a href='https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=111111111<</a>
```

which works perfectly. the thing that I am wondering now what is the different between the two. When I can use the second approach which is easier why should I use the first  approach? is there any advantage that the first approach  has and the second does not have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Difference is in User Interaction:**

**API:**

Retweet is an important feature, so it will be there in API. Applications built based on twitter API NEED this.

Once user authorizes the app, you can write a function which automates retweeting when the tweet contains certain words, etc. It needs no user interaction.

**URL:**

`https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=111111111`

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#retweet-intent

This needs user interaction. Clicking this link opens a popup where user HAVE to click a button to do the required action.